# Keycloak RestAPI: Assign client role to group

Tags: keycloak, rest

I have trying this:
url="https://{localhost}/auth/admin/realms/{realm_name}/groups/{group_id}/role-mappings"
payload=[{"id":"role_id","name":"Role_name","composite":"false","clientRole":"true","containerId":"client_id"}]

But, it doesnt work, i think it may be related to the wrong payload
Any ideas pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the  python-keycloak lib: https://pypi.org/project/python-keycloak/
there is a function: assign_group_client_roles

Answer (score 0):

The format is correct but you make sure the client has available payloaded role.
This is example for, "Hr" group added "RomoteApp" client the "tile limit" role.

In Keycloak UI, @ Client > RemoteApp > Roles

Role name

```
time limit
```

Groups > hr
Client Roles: RemoteApp
Available Roles: time limit
Assigned Roles: not yet include "time limit"

POST commend by Postman - I am not yet can attache image due to low level of stan overflow
http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/Test-realm/groups/9efef6bf-7edb-496e-bc0d-a8d4f5f4e3a9/role-mappings/clients/60a19179-f244-42f8-9950-04f2119a4e5b?client=RemoteApp&id=60a19179-f244-42f8-9950-04f2119a4e5b&realm=Test-realm

in body of postman with row JSON option ( Content-Type : application/json )

```
[
    {
        "id": "e17f9f7f-62dc-4998-b058-49b845ff5cef",
        "name": "time limit",
        "description": "time limit",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": "60a19179-f244-42f8-9950-04f2119a4e5b"
    }
]
```

group list

```
   {
        "id": "9efef6bf-7edb-496e-bc0d-a8d4f5f4e3a9",
        "name": "hr",
        "path": "/hr",
        "subGroups": []
    }
```

client list

```
    {
        "id": "60a19179-f244-42f8-9950-04f2119a4e5b",
        "clientId": "RemoteApp",
     ...
    }
```

also don't remember the access token called by  token endpoint w/ grant_type is `password`

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/realms/Test-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```